# How do i make that when i draw a line in green it will draw automatic each 10 pixels a red point?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the top of form1 i did:

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
GraphicsPath redgp = new GraphicsPath();
Point p;
```

Then in pictureBox1 move event i did:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
            if (panning)
            {
                movingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - startingPoint.X,
                                        e.Location.Y - startingPoint.Y);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                gp.AddLine(e.X * xFactor, e.Y * yFactor, e.X * xFactor, e.Y * yFactor);//e.Location, e.Location);
                redgp.AddEllipse((e.X) * xFactor, (e.Y) * yFactor, 3f, 3f);
                p = e.Location;
                pictureBox2.Invalidate();
            }

        }
```

Then in pictureBox2 paint event:

```
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                Pen p;
                p = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
                foreach (PointF pt in points)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X, pt.Y, 3f, 3f);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (points.Count > 1)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, points[i].X, points[i].Y, points[i + 1].X, points[i + 1].Y);
                    }
                }

                if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    using (Pen pp = new Pen(Color.Green, 2f))
                    {
                        pp.StartCap = pp.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                        pp.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pp, gp);
                    }
                    using (Pen pp = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f))
                    {
                        pp.StartCap = pp.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                        pp.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pp, redgp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When checkbox2 checked and i click on the mouse left button pressed and then move the mouse around on picturebox1 it will draw a line in pictureBox2.

The line in pictureBox2 is in green.
I want that while im moving the mouse on picturebox1 it will draw the line in green on pictureBox2 and also automatic each 10 pixels space in picutreBox2 it will draw a point automatic on the green line.

So i added this code to the pictureBox1 move event:

```
redgp.AddEllipse((e.X) * xFactor, (e.Y) * yFactor, 3f, 3f);
```

And in the picturebox2 paint event:

```
using (Pen pp = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f))
                    {
                        pp.StartCap = pp.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                        pp.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pp, redgp);
                    }
```

But what it does is just drawing wider line in Red in pictureBox2 on or near the green line. not what i wanted it to do.

How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by this way.
Added to top of form1 a variable counter.

Then picturebox1 mouse move event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
            if (panning)
            {
                movingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - startingPoint.X,
                                        e.Location.Y - startingPoint.Y);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                gp.AddLine(e.X * xFactor, e.Y * yFactor, e.X * xFactor, e.Y * yFactor);
                pixelscounter += 1;
                if (pixelscounter == 10)
                {
                    redgp.AddEllipse((e.X) * xFactor, (e.Y) * yFactor, 3f, 3f);
                    pixelscounter = 0;
                }
                p = e.Location;
                pictureBox2.Invalidate();
            }

        }
```

I make the counter  to go up by 1.
If its 10 create a red point. And reset the counter to 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

The line is Wider (Thick) because you have used PEN with 2f.
It Only Shows you RED as you are drawing two line of same thickness on same point,so what happens here is that you can only see the last line you drawn. In your case it is RED.

If you want both line to appear here then ;

User green Pen as it is:
                using (Pen pp = new Pen(Color.Green, 2f))

But make red pen Thinner :
                using (Pen pp = new Pen(Color.Red, 1f))

So, it will draw RED line On Green Line.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: No i dont want to see or draw both lines. I want to draw only the green line and while im drawing it automatic it will create on the green line every 10 pixels in spaces of 10 pixels red points. So lets say i start to draw the green line now the green line lnegth is 13(im not sure the units) then on 10 create a red point on the green line. Now i keep drawing the green line im getting to 20 the green line length now is 20 create another point on this place on the green line. And so on each 10 pixels length on the green line create/put a red point.

Comment: So is that mean you want to Draw RED Pixel at Every 10 location ?

Comment: Yes red pixel every 10 location on the green line ! While im drawing the green line i want it automatic to draw red pixel on the green line every 10 location. Excatly.